# Assign a numeric value conditional on string match between different data sets in R?

Tags: r, dataset, match

I have two data frames, one (called "mad") which contains economic data on every country for the period 1960-2016 where each country-year is one row. The other data frame (called "ccodes") consists of country names in one column and a numeric country code in the other column.

I would like to loop through the data frame which contains the economic data ( called "mads"), match country names between data frames, and then assign the correct numeric country code to a new column in the first data frame. Once I can assign the economic data the country codes, I plan on merging various data sets by country.

I've tried using grep but I can't figure out how to take matches and assign the corresponding numeric country code, conditional on a match. My code using grep looks like this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(mad)){
  country <- mad$country[i]
  if (grep(country, ccodes$statenme)){
    mad$ccode <- ccodes$ccode
  }
}
```

which returns the following error message:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "ccode", value = c(2L, 20L, 31L, 40L,  : 
  replacement has 243 rows, data has 11389
```

Is there some function already out there which I can use to accomplish this task, or is actually looping through the best way?

**EDIT: This package for country codes already exists. It is called countrycode, and you can read about it here. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/countrycode/countrycode.pdf.

Comment: please reproduce your sample code

Comment: Your `for` loop is incremented incorrectly, it should be `i in 1:nrow(mads)`, currently the value `i` will only go to the last element

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I've updated my code and added the error message I get.

Comment: I would eventually like to merge datasets by the numeric country code, which is what I'm trying to establish here. The problem is the dataframe "mad" doesn't have the country codes yet.

Comment: They are all different, as each data source uses a unique system for naming the countries. I haven't heard of fuzzy_join, but thanks for sending that I'll check it out.

Comment: First time posting, I'll be sure to do that next time. I ended up finding a package called countrycode which does exactly what I'm looking for but thanks for responding!